# Is there a more rapid method to download gcc-cilkplus?

Tags: gcc, download, cilk-plus

I am trying to create a parallel application in C++ and I chose to use the [Intel Cilk-Plus Libraries](https://www.cilkplus.org/) for this reason.

My problem is just that I am still trying to download the extension for g++ and compile it on my machine, but this thing is taking ages. As explained in the [Intel Cilk Library installation doc](https://www.cilkplus.org/build-gcc-cilkplus), I am trying to get the compiler sources to compile them. I am actually trying to go for the GCC 4.9 release.

#### Trying SVN...

I did try using `svn` but this is very slow and many times the program fails and forces me to restart from where it broke.

#### Trying GIT...

When I try git it is even worse. The command executes but the program fails telling me that there is ome broken stuff on server side... Guess their git repository is not well-formed.

#### Bruteforse: WGET

So I decided to cut the head to the chicken and have a direct recursive download using `wget`:

```
wget -r -l 0 -np --erobots=off http://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/branches/cilkplus/
```

It has been downloading since yesterday... I there a damn tarball to download or I really need to download using `wget` without any progress info? Thankyou

Comment: Did you try with `git` as well?

Comment: Git is broken... I mean the repository on their server is not well cofigured or something 'cause it always fails upon request... I mean it does not even start downloading, it rejects my request!

Comment: `ruby <(curl -fsSkL http://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/branches/cilkplus/)` ?

Comment: Sad to hear. I usually prefer to fetch the sources with `git`. I tried method 3 and altough it took a few to generate the tar, the download was fast.

Comment: @AdriC.S.: Sorry could you please tell me more? You used method 3? You mean like me `wget`?

Comment: No. In the install docs, there is a section labelled **a. cilkplus**. Under it there is a subsection labelled **iii. Using a snapshot**. I clicked on the link provided there. When the page is open, look for the first link. It should have a name like **[gcc/]** and next to it 3 colored tags. In that line, on the right corner there's is a link named **snapshot**. Click it and let's see if you get the tarball.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about C++ programming.

Comment: Yeah I am removing the c++ tag probably it is not needed here. But no need to vote for closing, I still think this can be a useful question...

Comment: @AdriC.S.: Believe me I could not find the iii option. Reloaded the page and it appeared!!!!! o_O

Comment: So, could you download the package?

Comment: Yeah I could find a tar... it is downloading it. Well, I guess this is it... Please post an answer, I'll check it!

Comment: Let's wait until you can confirm you have the right package.

Comment: Ok! Still downloading btw...

Comment: Yeah I unzipped everything and... there it is... It's ok!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As asked by the OP, I'll post my comment as an answer.

To get the `cilk-plus` sources as a tarball:

1. In the install docs, there is a section labelled **a. cilkplus**. Under it there is a subsection labelled **iii. Using a snapshot**.
2. In that subsection there is a link to the `gcc` git repository. Click on it.
3. When the webpage is loaded, search at the top for the first link. At the time of writing this it was named **[gcc/]**. However, the name may change.
   The link we need is the one with colored tags next to it.
4. Once located search, in the same line, for a link named **snapshot** at the right corner.
5. Click on it and wait while the tarball is generated.

**NOTE:** The link provided in the docs sometimes point to a rather old revision of the source code. To get the most recent one (1 or 2 days old at most) click on the **summary** section in the menu bar. There should appear an entry with the colored tags *master* and *trunk* next to it.